# Using Github as a update source

Tags: git, github, updates, mqtt

I'm developing a software for Raspberry Pi. As it will be a mobile system, I thought of using Github as the repo to get updates. It doesn't have to be Github actually but any git repo is fine. The question is whether the following flow works or not.

1) When there is a update I publish to the update topic on MQTT.
2) Subscribers get the message and run a system-wide command:
     - `git pull`
     - `download new dependencies if there is any`
     - `run makefile`
     - `restart the application`
3) Updated system publishes a message with the new version number.

The security of the repo will be achieved with ssh keys and the repo will definitely be private. The data loss while the application restarts is negligible.

I do not plan to use any update framework as this flow looks like it is easier to code than configuring an additional framework.

**Am I missing any key points on this flow?**

Answer (score 1):

A list of things to be considered:

1. How will you secure access to the MQTT broker?
2. What happens if the network connection drops mid update?
3. What is the rollback strategy for when you publish a broken update? (you will at some point)
4. How will you stagger updates to prevent DoSing your repo and to ensure quality of updates as they are pushed?
5. Why do you think you can do a better job than any of the existing frameworks?
6. Rather than roll your own solution have you looked at any of the already available solutions e.g. http://resin.io/